# Get Recorded file from SDCard and attach it to email client

Tags: android, file, audio, path

I have implemented the audio recorder functionality in my application.Now I need to get the file and attach it to the GMailSender.How can I get the file.This is the code I tried to start video.There is a save button in my UI,when it gets clicked the audio file will automatically attached to the mail.

```
private void startRecord()
{ 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

        int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            minBufferSize);

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        while(recording)
        {
            int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++)
            {
                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
            }
        }
        audioRecord.stop();
        audioRecord.release();
        dataOutputStream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Please anyone help me!

Comment: So where is your code to attach file, are you getting any error or what???

Comment: No I not even tried.I dont know how to get the file which was used to record

Comment: if i am not wrong then you are strong your audio recorded file in SDCard right???

Comment: test.pcm is your file .. get its absolute path using file.getAbsolutepath() and then use it

Comment: @Jolly, try my below answer and tell me it is working or not.

Comment: @r4jiiv007 how can I pass the file from one activity to another

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to send email... Just use this code inside your onCreate Method and you are done with sending mail.

```
   String subject = "Your subject name";
   String message = "Message "

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("audio/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
            "email-id"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "path of audio file"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: I want to attach file using Gmail Sender instead of using Intent.Now my problem is cant able to get the recorded file path.Where I get that path?